# Nodetool repair - how to automate on linux & actions during repair

Tags: cassandra, nodetool, repair

Currently, I'm running once a week manually nodetool repair (while no action is happening to the cassandra nodes (nothing is inserted, e.t.c.)). Just wondering, if I can run nodetool repair, while data is being inserted?

Secondly - Can I create a script in crontab, that automatically runs every week nodetool repair, and is ocne a week enough to run nodetool repair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, if running one repair at a time you shouldn't be impacting normal usage. Instead of a cron job i would recommend using [reaper](http://cassandra-reaper.io/) (free and open source) for automating it. Would give you a bit more visibility and it handles things a bit better than just the default that running from nodetool provides.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can run repair while data is inserting it may impact your traffic so avoid this you can run repair table or key space wise.
Yes, you can run repair and schedule a crone for the same.